# MySQL: Select longest string that occurs in search string

Tags: mysql, string, select, wildcard

I have a table like this:

```
id    path
1     /
2     /city/
3     /city/europe/
4     /city/north america/
6     /city/europe/germany/berlin/
7     /city/europe/germany/
8     /city/north america/usa/
[...]
```

and a search string like this:

```
"/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/"
```

I need to select the longest path thats inside the search string so the result would be

```
id   path
8    /city/north america/usa/
```

Every parent to any path in the table exists. The paths can be arbitrarily long. The search string contains at least "/".

I can think of a few solutions like using wildcards on the column, splitting the search string and performing a select with IN or joins.

**What is the best and fastest way to do this?**

The table can be modified in any way.

EDIT:
The fastest solution with which I have come up so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE path IN ('/','/city/','/city/north america/', '/city/north  america/usa/', '/city/north america/usa/florida/', '/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/')
ORDER by LENGTH(path) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE path REGEXP '^/city((((/north america)?/usa)?/florida)?/miami)?\/?$'
ORDER BY LENGTH(path) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That does not work. It returns all columns (and limits this to one result, which in that case is the wrong one)

Comment: It works but it takes about 1000 times longer than this:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE path IN ('/','/city/','/city/north america/', '/city/north america/usa/', '/city/north america/usa/florida/', '/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/') ORDER by LENGTH(path) DESC LIMIT 1`

However, I think that is not the best solution there is.

Answer (score 0):

Or, try this one:

```
select * FROM tbl WHERE path=
( select max(path) from tbl 
  where '/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/' like concat(path,'%')
)
```

(Edit) 
Then maybe this is faster:

```
select * from tbl where instr('/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/',path)=1 
order by path desc limit 1
```

Comment: The subquery alone is enough, yet it is pretty slow compared to a WHERE IN select.

Comment: The second query is actually a bit slower. It has to apply the function to every row. I believe I can somehow use the b-tree index to my advantage by having a tree structure in the data.
I can, if necessary, also use a nested set but that makes the model a bit more complicated to manage.

Comment: Maybe there are some index issues with your table? My [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6bbd/6) with 84000 records needs about 16ms to complete.

Comment: As it turns out,  your [`WHERE IN (...)`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6196/4) and my version require the same execution time.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that the path column is unique. Testing with 50000 rows, the WHERE IN query takes <16ms, where the INSTR query takes about 100ms. Btw, the point of testing should be not to search for exact matches but to expect the search string to be deeper than the paths in the table.

Comment: Well, [my test on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70488/1) shows different results: 35ms for the `instr()` approach and 42ms for the `IN(...)` version. This time column `path` *is* unique and a substring *is* fitted, since there are paths like `'/city/north america/usa/florida/miami/park'` in the table.

Comment: ... and if you want the search path to be "deeper" than the contents in the column `path` then look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6595c/2) where I have relaced 'Miami' with 'NotMiami' in the table: Basically the same speed ratio ...

Comment: If I omit the index on the path column both queries do take approximately the same time (40-70ms). With a unique index it drops to <16ms for SELECT IN, and rises to 80-120ms with INSTR. This was tested on several machines/environments.
[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a93a4/1)

Comment: An interesting find that an index can make certain queries slower. Maybe some of the more senior SQL experts can explain this behaviour. I am clueless.